# Where is this castle?

Tags: where-on-earth, architecture, identify-this

where is [this](http://www.gtk.org/images/screenshots/screenshot-gimp-linux.jpg) castle/palace? someone suggested it was Vianden castle in Luxembourg but it's not.

Comment: BTW You can use tineye to do a [reverse image search](http://www.tineye.com/search/64dc0fad0ded3b93a8bef39167d38c36bb2d3982/?sort=score&order=asc)

Comment: @MartinSmith amazing, I've never seen that service before

Comment: I usually use TinEye in one tab and Google Image Search in another tab. They have different strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: Your link points to gtk.org. What has prevented you from actually pasting image directly to this question? Is this about licensing issues or... your laziness? :>

Comment: ...or an unawareness that pasting the image directly into the post was even an option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is [Neuschwanstein Castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuschwanstein_Castle) in Schwangau, Germany.

For more information about the castle and how to visit it, here is the [official website](http://www.neuschwanstein.de/englisch/palace/).

[image]

Photo from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Neuschwanstein_Castle_from_Marienbr%C3%BCcke,_2011_May.jpg)